# image gallery slider inside Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I want to create an image gallery inside a div, a very simple one. i want to be able to use it in a tablet so i need it to respond to swipe movements.

```
<div class="img-cont" style="display: block;">
    <img src="" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;">
    <img src="" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;">
    <img src="" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;">
    <img src="" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;">
    <img src="" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;">
</div>
```

Swipe is currently such a mainstream functionality why isn't there something simpler?

Like the one presented here but not so complicated:

http://smoothdivscroll.com/touchScroller.html

Comment: The demo you put uses several JS libraries, so it's bound to be a bit 'complicated'. You don't have to do everything from scratch as there are many free libraries even the most professional developers conveniently use.

Comment: The smoothdiv is not complicated you just need to add some proper classes and IDs in order to make the scrolling effect to work,Here is the description. http://smoothdivscroll.com/index.html#toc

Comment: well i get it, although i think it is a bit complicated no? i just want swipe effect why can't i just have div and images and some library that provides the swipe? since it is such a mainstream effect nowadays.

Comment: @BerdiyaOnur can you point some pls?